# how to refresh the context in entity framework 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to refresh context in entity framework 7 using asp.net 5. I get data from stored procedure but does't have result on time
this is my code for load stored procedure

```
 private DbSet<FeatureReport> DbFeatureReport { get; set; }

internal IEnumerable<FeatureReport> GetFeatureReport()
    {                        
        return DbFeatureReport.FromSql("EXEC [dbo].[FeatureReport]");
    }
```

Comment: What procedure you are following? what your outcome is? what your expected outcome?

Comment: when call stored procedure in entity framework 7 does't has last data that inserted or updated in sql server tables , should close and run again web page to load last data

Comment: You should show your `FromSql` fucntion. Could be that your `DbFeatureReport` class cache result somehow.

Comment: You don't "refresh" the context - the context doesn't actually contain any data. If your method doesn't return any data it's because *the SQL statement* didn't return any data. Or the code that calls `GetFeaturetReport` has a problem. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: FeatureReport is a stored procedure in my sql server database that gets data from others tables , when in web site update,insert  and any change on tables , this is code does't gets last data